# Why does MariaDB's default cast timestamp to integer method works this way?

Tags: casting, mariadb, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I recently noticed that casting a TIMESTAMP value:

```
SELECT CAST( timestamp_column_name AS int ) FROM table;
```

Which gives the same result as casting to a FLOAT, does not correspond to the 'natural' value that we would get by using the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function

It instead outputs the corresponding `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` integer, which isn't the easiest to work with...

Am I missing something?

(I used MariaDB 10.7)

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with the `CAST`? Why don't you use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`-function?

Comment: The cast method is used by default when such TIMESTAMP variable is used in an arithmetic operation with an INT and it makes no sense to me

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "cast method is used by default". Used by who? Can you give an example? In general, casting timestamp is rarely done.

Comment: Here is an example of default casting: `SELECT timestamp_column_name - 10 from table;`

Comment: The question was more like why would you do direct calculations based on timestamp column? What do you expect as a result?